# Calculating Total variation distance between two multivariate probability density?

Tags: probability, statistics

There are several probability metrics such as KL Divergence, and Hellinger distance that can be calculated in a closed form equation when two distributions are multivariate normal. With those metrics, some useful bounds for TV distance are already known.

However, I want to calculate the metric(specifically TV distance) directly in a countable space(discrete) with its definition if it is possible.

First, I'm trying to think with not that complicated examples which includes two random vector have +1 and -1 in each elements with probability 1/2.

If there are some empirical calculation tutorials or related references of Total variation distance or other probability metrics, please let me know.

Comment: Something along [these lines](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/36517/statistical-distance-between-uniform-and-biased-coin/36536#36536)?